# How to do a plot in 1000 pixels?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to plot 1600 points to a graph (only graph, not counting axes and whitespaces) 1000 **pixels** wide. Is this method of setting the inches and pixels per inch (DPI) the best way? Is there a better way?

```
self.figure, (self.picture, self.intensity) = \
        plt.subplots(nrows=2, figsize=(10, 5))
    self.figure.set_dpi(100)
```

Comment: I believe this is the correct and only way. You can just put `figsize=(10,5), dpi=100`, if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a figure of 1600 pixels wide and 1000 pixels high you could do something like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(16, 10), dpi=100)
# ... your code
plt.savefig(filename)
```